# sqlite multiple query conditions

Tags: sqlite

I've searched but can't find the right answer, and I'm going round in circles.
I have

```
CREATE TABLE History (yr Int, output Int, cat Text);
yr          output      cat
----------  ----------  ----------
2015        10          a
2016        20          a
2017        30          a
2018        50          a
2019        70          a
2015        100         b
2016        200         b
2017        300         b
2018        500         b
2019        700         b
2015        1000        c
2016        2000        c
2017        3000        c
2018        5000        c
2019        7000        c
2015        10000       d
2016        20000       d
2017        30000       d
2018        50000       d
2019        70000       d
```

I've created two views

```
CREATE VIEW Core AS select  * from History where cat = "c" or cat = "d";

CREATE VIEW Plus AS select  * from History where cat = "a" or cat = "b";
```

My query is

```
select distinct yr, sum(output), (select sum(output) from core  group by yr) as _core, (select sum(output) from plus  group by yr) as _plus from history group by yr;

yr          sum(output)  _core       _plus
----------  -----------  ----------  ----------
2015        11110        11000       110
2016        22220        11000       110
2017        33330        11000       110
2018        55550        11000       110
2019        77770        11000       110
```

Each of the individual queries works but _core and _plus columns are wrong when it's all put together.  How should I approach this please.

Comment: What are you wanting those values to be?

Comment: Also: SQL uses single quotes for strings, not double quotes. Plus since you're grouping by yr you shouldn't need that DISTINCT.

Comment: @Shawn double quotes _sometimes_ work in SQLite too, so long as what's inside the double quotes doesn't happen to be a table or column name.  Best to use single quotes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's for the best to pretend that particular quirk of sqlite doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may generate your expected output without a view, using a single query with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    yr,
    SUM(output) AS sum_output,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cat IN ('c', 'd') THEN output ELSE 0 END) AS _core,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cat IN ('a', 'b') THEN output ELSE 0 END) AS _plus
FROM History
GROUP BY
    yr;
```

If you really wanted to make your current approach work, one way would be to just join the two views by year.  But that would leave open the possibility that each view might not have every year present.